# Unwanted white space with knitr+booktabs package

Tags: tables, knitr, booktabs

I want to include a table in my latex document that I create using knitr package. I "call" the table using:

```
\begin{table}[H]
\begin{centering}
<<r second part}>>=
kable(Per_cond, booktabs=F,row.names=F)
@
\par\end{centering}
\begin{centering}
\protect\caption{Summary of plate}
\par\end{centering}
\label{Table}
\end{table}
```

The results is amazing as usual, but as you can see below, some white space is added after every 5 rows.

[image: Booktabs ON table]

When created with `booktabs=F` those withe spaces disappear (second image).

[image: Booktabs OFF table]

Do you know a way to get rid of those white spaces or (even better) to select where they appear (in this case if they would come after every 4 rows, they would nicely separate my conditions) ? Thank you for your help.

(RStudio 0.98.1062, knitr v 1.9, MikTex 2.9, booktabs packaged 2005-05-04)

Comment: This question was solved: [solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29350664/unwanted-white-space-with-knitrbooktabs-package)

Answer (score 4):

This question was crossposted at [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29350664)
and got an answer from [Gregor](https://stackoverflow.com/users/903061/gregor) that helped the OP.

---

Looking at the source of `kable`, it calls `knitr:::kable_latex` if you're using LaTeX. Then, looking at that source, it has the following argument and default:

```
linesep = if (booktabs) c("", "", "", "", "\\addlinespace")
```

So, I'm guessing if you explicitly pass

```
linesep = c("", "", "", "\\addlinespace")
```

you'll get spaces every 4 lines as desired.